# Carousel In Partial View Not Rendering

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-modal, carousel

I have an ajax call that returns a partial view (carousel with images) and places it within a `Modal`. Everything is working correctly but the carousel doesn't display the images right away.

If I press F12 or resize the window the images render. Or if I cycle through both images using the carousel controls the images show on the second round away.

The modal is in a partial on the main view on page load but holds no content until the ajax returns the images.

```
@Html.Partial("_ImageCarouselModal")
```

Do I need to redraw the carousel or is it down to the ordering of initialisation?

Here is my current ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/GetImages",
    success: function (data) {

        $("#imageModal .modal-body").html(data);
        $("#imageModal").modal('show');
        carousel();
    }
});

function carousel() {
    $('.image-carousel').slick({
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        fade: true,
        cssEase: 'linear',
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        accessibility: false
    });
}
```

The modal is you standard HTMl modal.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is your `ajax` type, "POST"? You aren't posting data to the server.

Comment: I'm posting a reference, I just removed it to simply the code so it didn't have unnecessary code

Comment: Ok. So what you placed in your example is not the code you are using? Seems kind of counter productive to place psuedo code in your post, but hey, to each their own.

Comment: I just removed the data parameter of the ajax call because it a few properties that were just clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I typed this out I saw a quick fix for this issue and its working correctly. It's not elegant but its working.

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('.image-carousel').resize();
});
```